# Adding numbers to a list

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am building a torrent scraper for educational purposes. I am wanting to learn web scraping so I thought this would be a good way of doing so. Anyways I am trying to have a list of torrents print out numbered, but when I try to do a for loop adding numbers to the torrents in the list I cannot use the same variables because they are converted to a string. How can I solve this? Here is the code I am working with.

```
for torrent in torrents:
    print (str (torrent + 1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you explain what you mean by "print out numbered"? Do you mean the index within the list then

```
for index, torrent in enumerate(torrents):
  print(str(index) + ', ' + str(torrent))
```

would give you

```
0, torrent0String
1, torrent1String
...
```

Comment: Yeah, I am wanting the list be numbered such as.
```
1 string
2 string
3 string
and so on